# how to unit test following Method, returning value using "ref"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stored-procedures, nunit, ref

I have similar methods in the business layer. I am new to unit testing and sometimes get confused. For an idea, can you suggest, what will be a better approach to test this method
behaviour? I am using C# NUnit and Moq

```
public int? AddNewCatRetID(string categoryName)
{
  int? categoryID = 0;
  Adapter.AddNewBlogCategoryReturnID(categoryName, ref categoryID);

  if (categoryID.HasValue)
    return categoryID;

  return 0;
}
```

where

`Adapter` = Visual Studio 2008, Data Set Designer generated TableAdater

`AddDeveloperCategoryReturnID()` = Name of a function which utilises a Stored procedure in DB

It adds a new record,  "Category" and returns its auto generated ID. If it is non zero, we take that result for further processing.

I know should not be interested in talking to Database, below is the procedure, just to give an idea about what is going on in DB

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDeveloperCategoryReturnID]

@NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CATEGORY_ID INT OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [AllTimeGreatProgrammersDateBase].dbo.CATEGORIES(NAME )
 VALUES (@NAME );

 SET @CATEGORY_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

 SELECT @CATEGORY_ID;
END
```

some issues

- how to check the values returned using "ref" from the method
- what will you prefer to test and not to test? will be great if can list

Comment: Why are you using a ref parameter in the first place? Just make it a return value.

Comment: Why is categoryId Nullable? If you cast it to int and it's null you will get an exception.

Comment: @jon Skeet: using ref as not sure how to return result from stored procedure.
@magnus: fixed as per your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first convert `Adapter.AddNewBlogCategoryReturnID(categoryName, ref categoryID)` so that instead of returning a variable by reference, it simply returned the value.

Then, I would extract that into a virtual method.

To test `AddNewCatRetID`, I would extend the class to make a testable version, and override that virtual method to return an `int?` stored in a public variable.

That way, when you test to see what happens when you call `AddNewCatRetID` in a situation where there's a 0 in the database, you don't need to actually put a 0 in the database - you just set that parameter on the testable version of your class, and when your test calls `AddNewCatRetID`, instead if hitting the database, it just returns the value you set.  Your test is guaranteed to be faster if you can avoid hitting the database, and since it's MS's generated adapter, there's not really a need to test it - you only care about what your method does with what the adapter returns.

Comment: how will you test a "ref",  'if' it is the only / best option ?

Comment: If `ref` is the only option, I would have the virtual method also return the value by ref.  To be honest, I'm not very familiar with returning by ref, but if I understand correctly, you would set the value of the ref variable to the value of your public field.

Comment: virtual method is auto generated by designer. One option I have tried is wrapping up this auto generated method into my custom method that gets the required result and returns it normally., but just for the sake of unit test

Answer (score 2):

There are several options depending on the characteristics of the Adapter type. If AddDeveloperCategoryReturnID is **virtual** or an **interface** member, you can most likely use a [Test Double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) (either a hand-rolled one or a dynamic mock) to replace its behavior with some test-specific behavior.

If is a **non-virtual** method, you have two options:

- Refactor the method to make it more testable.
- Write an automated test that involves a database round-trip.

Automated tests that involve the database are orders of magnitudes more difficult to write and maintain than pure unit tests, so I would tend to shoot for the refactoring option.

On the other hand, if you think that the stored procedure represents a valuable code asset that should be protected by an automated test, you have no recourse but to write the database test.

Comment: it is a virtual method, this is signature:
public virtual object AddDeveloperCategoryReturnID(string NAME, ref global::System.Nullable<int> CATEGORY_ID) {// designer generated code}

Comment: You may be able to mock it then, but it depends on what `Adapter` is. Is it a public writable property or a public virtual property. In the first case you can replace it with a Test Double. In the latter case, you can use the Extract & Override unit testing pattern.